# Cypress cutting down "X-CSRFToken" header

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, cypress, csrf-token

Noticed that Cypress test runner is cutting out `X-CSRFToken` from the request header, which causes the request to return `403 Forbidden`. Here is the screenshot of headers from manual run and Cypress test run,

**Screenshot taken while navigating in Chrome browser:**
[image]

**Screenshot taken while running Cypress test:**
[image]

To confirm this, I replayed the request through `curl` attaching the `X-CSRFToken`. It worked fine then. How could I handle this while running Cypress tests?

**NOTE:** This happens on performing drag and drop events using `trigger()` function

Comment: How are you logging in to your application? Are you using cy.request? Is your token stored in localStorage?

Comment: I notice this behavior only when I have series of test steps mentioned in separated `it()` functions. If I put all the tests in a single `it()` function, I see this issue disappear. To answer your question, I'm checking the network logs from chrome DevTools. The requests are fired by the application under test. The tokens are stored in `Cookies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stumbled upon this problem and could solve it:

Use the `cy.session()` command to preserve the session data(Cookies) while running your tests.
[See cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Syntax).

**Example solution from my app:**

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'login',
  (username, password) => {
    
    cy.session('user', () => { // <-- using command here
    // First login request to DJANGO which sets
    // Cookies (XSRF-TOKEN, session_id)
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiUrl,
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        },
        body: {
          password: pw,
          username: user,
        },
      }).then((response) => {
        const user = response.body.user
        user.token = response.body.access_token

        window.localStorage.setItem('auth.currentUser', JSON.stringify(user))
      })
    })
  })
```

Then in my test the cookies are already set:

```
 it('Logs in as Premium User create a team and delete it', () => {
    cy.login('user', 'password')

    // do test requests which rely on XSRF-TOKEN being set here
  })
```

---

Since this `cy.session()` feature is relatively new you may have to set a flag in your `cypress.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
    // ....
  }
```

Hope this helps somebody :)

Answer (score 1):

Cypress automatically clears cookies between each test, so while you would have set your cookies correctly when logging in, they would have been discarded as soon as that `it` (or `specify`, `describe` or `context`) block finished. This means any subsequent network requests will have a fresh state (by design).

In order to get around this, you can use `Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce`: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies.html#Preserve-Once

Here's how I used it to get around a similar problem:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('XSRF-TOKEN', 'session_id')
    })
```

And if you are looking to maintain that state across *all* your test suites (ie: separate `spec.js` files), you can place this in your `cypress/support/index.js` file:

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
    preserve: ['XSRF-TOKEN', 'session_id']
})
```

Comment: > The Cypress.Cookies.defaults and Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce APIs been removed. Use the cy.session() command to preserve cookies (and local and session storage) between tests.

Source: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Migrating-to-Cypress-130